# Explanation why determinant expression with repeating lower indices is zero

Tags: determinant, tensors

On page-141 of Tensor Analysis by Pavel Grinfeld, in eqtn 9.46 it is said that the quantity:

> $$\delta_{rst}^{123} a_2^r a_2^s a_3^t$$
>
> Where, $\delta_{rst}^{123} = e_{rst} e^{123}$ with $e_{ijk}, e^{rst}$ being the permutation symbols, $a_i^j$ representing entry in ith row and jth column in a matrix, r,s,t ranges from $1 \to 3$ (meaning each can take three different values)

Is zero with the reason being given that the lower index repeat, but I don't get how the lower indice repeating causes it to be zero. Hope someone can explain.

For reference, the determinant in this book is defined in the following way:

$$|A| = \frac{\delta_{rst}^{ijk} }{3!} a_i^r a_j^s a_k^t$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\delta_{r,s,t}^{1,2,3}=-\delta_{s,r,t}^{1,2,3}$ and $a_2^s a_2^r a_3^t=a_2^r a_2^s a_3^t$. So,(since dummy indices can be interchanged for the middle equality), we have
$$
\delta_{r,s,t}^{1,2,3}a_2^r a_2^s a_3^t = - \delta_{s,r,t}^{1,2,3}a_2^r a_2^s a_3^t =
- \delta_{r,s,t}^{1,2,3} a_2^s a_2^r a_3^t =
- \delta_{r,s,t}^{1,2,3} a_2^r a_2^r a_3^t
$$
Since this number is its own negative it is 0 since we are dealing with real numbers.

Comment: Thank you, I had missed the point that you could swap indices on the delta symbol ^^